# How to store and use closures that use a common region of memory?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a piece of Rust code that simulates a small (typed) toy language with closures, but I'm not sure how I should store them in an `enum` so that they are still able to access/use a common heap when I evaluate the closures.

I'd like the program's data to be stored on a heap, and I allow all of the closures to take in this heap as an argument in case it needs to allocate something, retrieve a value, etc. I'm okay if the closure code itself is dynamically allocated by Rust, but I want the pointers to the closures themselves to be in my `Heap` struct.

I've tried storing the data as a function pointer (like `fn(usize, usize, &mut Heap)`), as well as boxed closures (like `Box<dyn FnMut(usize, &mut Heap) -> usize>`), as well as a boxed pointer version with a lifetime argument (like `Box<dyn FnMut(usize, &mut Heap) -> usize + 'a>`) but I always seem to run into some issue with the borrow checker.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
enum Val {
    Int(i32),
    Bool(bool),
    Lambda(Box<dyn FnMut(usize, &mut Heap) -> usize>),
}

struct Heap {
    mem: Vec<Val>,
}

impl Heap {
    fn alloc(&mut self, v: Val) -> usize {
        self.mem.push(v);
        self.mem.len() - 1
    }

    fn get(&self, i: usize) -> &Val {
        &self.mem[i]
    }
}

fn apply(func: usize, arg: usize, heap: &mut Heap) -> usize {
    let closure = match heap.get(func) {
        Val::Lambda(x) => x,
        _ => panic!(),
    };
    closure(arg, heap)
}

fn main() {
    let mut h = Heap { mem: vec![] };

    // creating a closure
    let foo = Val::Lambda(Box::new(|a: usize, mut heap: &mut Heap| -> usize {
        let a_val = match heap.get(a) {
            Val::Int(x) => *x,
            _ => panic!(),
        };
        heap.alloc(Val::Int(a_val * a_val))
    }));
    let f = h.alloc(foo);

    // using the closure
    let a = h.alloc(Val::Int(3));
    let b = apply(f, a, &mut h);
    match h.get(b) {
        Val::Int(x) => println!("{}", x),
        _ => panic!(),
    };
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0caf1ebe71767409db0a9f30c27d6c1a)

The above code should output 9, but instead there is a borrow-checker error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `**closure` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/main.rs:27:5
   |
23 |     let closure = match heap.get(func) {
   |         ------- help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut std::boxed::Box<dyn for<'r> std::ops::FnMut(usize, &'r mut Heap) -> usize>`
...
27 |     closure(arg, heap)
   |     ^^^^^^^ `closure` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*heap` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:27:5
   |
23 |     let closure = match heap.get(func) {
   |                         ---- immutable borrow occurs here
...
27 |     closure(arg, heap)
   |     -------^^^^^^^^^^^
   |     |
   |     mutable borrow occurs here
   |     immutable borrow later used by call

warning: variable does not need to be mutable
  --> src/main.rs:34:47
   |
34 |     let foo = Val::Lambda(Box::new(|a: usize, mut heap: &mut Heap| -> usize {
   |                                               ----^^^^
   |                                               |
   |                                               help: remove this `mut`
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_mut)] on by default
```

Is it possible to clone my closures / enum to mitigate this borrowing issue? I am not sure if this is possible due to the restrictions on [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) listed by the Rust documentation:

> "Closure types, if they capture no value from the environment or if all such captured values implement `Clone` themselves. Note that variables captured by shared reference always implement `Clone` (even if the referent doesn't), while variables captured by mutable reference never implement `Clone`."

Comment: What you are attempting to do is inherently memory unsafe. You have a reference to something in a vector and potentially try to mutate it while that reference is outstanding. That could invalidate the reference. This is exactly what Rust prevents — introducing memory unsafety.

Comment: Search on stack overflow for the error message you get and you'll find hundreds of questions about the same thing.

Comment: Your immediate error is solved by [How can I pass a FnMut closure to a function using a reference in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43069178/155423). Then you run into [Cannot borrow as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47618823/155423)

Comment: Gotcha, thanks @Shepmaster. I'm familiar with the general borrow checking aspect, I was just trying to think if there was any way to reformulate my code that deals with the pass-in-heap part more safely.

Comment: For the time being I've fixed my code by changing my `Val::Lambda` to take in a function pointer instead, and make all of the functions/lambdas/closures at the top level (i.e. global).